# Display a clean list from json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to display in a list all the elements of my json.

I have a var "json" containing all my data.

What I exactly want is display the datas like this :

```
   <ul>
     <li>title + "of the first element"</li>
     <li>title + "of the second element"</li>
     <li>title + "of the third element"</li>
   </ul>
```

Every time I try something with a simple "for", it only display me the last element.

The closest solution I had was with this I think:

```
function displayJson(){

    $.each(json, function(key, value) {
        $(this).html("<li>" + json[key].title + "</li>");
     });

}
```

I'm a beginner, any help would be really appreciated !

Comment: Please edit your question by providing us an example of the json you want to display

Comment: One change I can suggest even just with the info in the question: Use `value.title` rather than `json[key].title`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the function you're giving `$.each`, `this` will be the value of the entry in the `json` object, not a DOM element, so you can't generate the output that way.

Assuming that `json` refers to an object that contains objects, each of which has a `title` property, then:

```
var $ul = $("some selector for the list");
var json = /*...wherever you're getting the object from... */;
displayJson($ul, json);

function displayJson($ul, json) {
    $ul.empty(); // If it might have something in it
    $.each(json, function(key, value) {
        $ul.append($("<li>").html(value.title));
    });
}
```